Unknown type name 'ImVec2'
I am trying to build the hello_imgui_template with Cmake, but I am unable to proceed without it giving me hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h file not found.
Just to try it out I manually inserted the absolute paths in every #include so that at least it changes the error, which it did.
Now the hello_world.main.cpp complies with fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 8 warnings and 20 errors generated   of which several are
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:123:1: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
ImVec2 EmToVec2(float x, float y);
also /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui_logger.h:27:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec2'.
I really do not understand where this error is coming from and how to resolve it.
My c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Where you can see I already tried editing in Include path the folders
My settings.json:
{
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++"
}

My hello_imgui.main.cpp:
#include "/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h"

int main(int , char *[])
{
    auto guiFunction = []() {
        ImGui::Text("Hello, ");                    // Display a simple label
        HelloImGui::ImageFromAsset("world.jpg");   // Display a static image
        if (ImGui::Button("Bye!"))                 // Display a button
            // and immediately handle its action if it is clicked!
            HelloImGui::GetRunnerParams()->appShallExit = true;
     };
    HelloImGui::Run(guiFunction, "Hello, globe", true);
    return 0;
}

The CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(helloworld_with_helloimgui)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


# Build hello_imgui
# =================
# 1/  Option 1: if you added hello_imgui as a subfolder, you can add it to your project with:
if(IS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/hello_imgui)
    add_subdirectory(external/hello_imgui)
endif()

# 2/  Option 2: simply fetch hello_imgui during the build
if (NOT TARGET hello_imgui)
    message(STATUS "Fetching hello_imgui")
    include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(hello_imgui GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pthom/hello_imgui.git GIT_TAG master)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(hello_imgui)
endif()

# 3/  Option 3: via vcpkg
# i/ You can install hello_imgui via vcpkg with:
#     vcpkg install "hello-imgui[opengl3-binding,glfw-binding]"
# ii/ Then you can use it inside CMake with:
#     find_package(hello-imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)


# Build your app
# ==============
hello_imgui_add_app(hello_world_ hello_world.main.cpp)


# hello_imgui_add_app is a helper function, similar to cmake's "add_executable"
# Usage:
# hello_imgui_add_app(app_name file1.cpp file2.cpp ...)
#
# Features: 
# * It will automatically link the target to the required libraries (hello_imgui, OpenGl, glad, etc)
# * It will embed the assets (for desktop, mobile, and emscripten apps)
# * It will perform additional customization (app icon and name on mobile platforms, etc)

# Now you can build your app with
#     mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && cmake --build .

If someone is curious, yes I already build the app with the command you see above, but the errors persist.
The build log is:
[proc] Esecuzione del comando: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake --version
[proc] Esecuzione del comando: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake -E capabilities
[variant] Il nuovo set di varianti è stato caricato
[kit] I 1 kit sono stati caricati da /Users/alessandrodoro/.local/share/CMakeTools/cmake-tools-kits.json
[proc] Il comando: ninja --version non è riuscito con errore: Error: spawn ninja ENOENT
[proc] Il comando: ninja-build --version non è riuscito con errore: Error: spawn ninja-build ENOENT
[main] Configurazione del progetto: hello_imgui_template-1 
[proc] Esecuzione del comando: /opt/homebrew/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE --no-warn-unused-cli -S/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1 -B/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- HELLOIMGUI_WITH_TEST_ENGINE=OFF
[cmake] -- Library hello_imgui
[cmake] -- Added installable dependency stb_hello_imgui, HELLOIMGUI_INSTALLABLE_DEPENDENCIES=stb_hello_imgui
[cmake] -- HELLOIMGUI_USE_IMGUI_CMAKE_PACKAGE is OFF
[cmake] -- Added installable dependency imgui, HELLOIMGUI_INSTALLABLE_DEPENDENCIES=stb_hello_imgui;imgui
[cmake] -- HelloImGui: downloading and building freetype
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/freetype-src/CMakeLists.txt:113 (cmake_minimum_required):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
[cmake] CMake Warning at build/_deps/freetype-src/builds/cmake/FindHarfBuzz.cmake:99 (message):
[cmake]   Required version (2.0.0) is higher than found version ()
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   build/_deps/freetype-src/CMakeLists.txt:258 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Could NOT find BrotliDec (missing: BROTLIDEC_INCLUDE_DIRS BROTLIDEC_LIBRARIES) 
[cmake] CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/lunasvg-src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
[cmake]   Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
[cmake]   CMake.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
[cmake]   CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Added installable dependency lunasvg, HELLOIMGUI_INSTALLABLE_DEPENDENCIES=stb_hello_imgui;imgui;lunasvg
[cmake] -- Added installable dependency hello_imgui, HELLOIMGUI_INSTALLABLE_DEPENDENCIES=stb_hello_imgui;imgui;lunasvg;hello_imgui
[cmake] -- HelloImGui: using nlohmann_json from external/nlohmann_json
[cmake] -- Added installable dependency nlohmann_json, HELLOIMGUI_INSTALLABLE_DEPENDENCIES=stb_hello_imgui;imgui;lunasvg;hello_imgui;nlohmann_json
[cmake] -- Found system lib glfw3
[cmake] -- Added installable dependency glad, HELLOIMGUI_INSTALLABLE_DEPENDENCIES=stb_hello_imgui;imgui;lunasvg;hello_imgui;nlohmann_json;glad
[cmake] -- 
[cmake]     ===========================================================================
[cmake]         Hello ImGui build options:
[cmake]     ===========================================================================
[cmake]       Platform Backend(s):              HELLOIMGUI_USE_GLFW3
[cmake]       Rendering Backend(s):             HELLOIMGUI_HAS_OPENGL3
[cmake]     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake]       Options:
[cmake]         HELLOIMGUI_USE_FREETYPE:        ON  (Use target freetype)
[cmake]         HELLOIMGUI_WITH_TEST_ENGINE:    OFF
[cmake]         BUILD_DEMOS - TESTS - DOCS:     OFF - OFF - OFF
[cmake]     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake]       ImGui:
[cmake]         Build ImGui:                    ON
[cmake]         ImGui source dir:               external/imgui
[cmake]     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake]       nlohmann_json:                    Using external/nlohmann_json
[cmake]     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake]       OpenGL - use glad loader          ON
[cmake]     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake]       Platform Backend(s):
[cmake]         Glfw:                           Use system Library
[cmake]     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[cmake]       macOS:
[cmake]         HELLOIMGUI_MACOS_NO_BUNDLE:     OFF
[cmake]     ===========================================================================
[cmake] -- Configuring done (5.0s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.2s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/build

I cannot share the header file where I get the errors (dpi_aware.h)as the body of the text reaches well over 30000 characters, but you can find it in https://github.com/pthom/hello_imgui.git
The complete log after compiling is:
(base) alessandrodoro@MBP-Alessandro hello_imgui_template-1 % cd "/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/" && g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o
 tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/"tempCodeRunnerFile
In file included from tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h:9:
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:59:31: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    float dpiWindowSizeFactor = 0.0f;
                              ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:70:30: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    float fontRenderingScale = 0.0f;
                             ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:75:35: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    bool onlyUseFontDpiResponsive = false;
                                  ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:85:37: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    int             fontOversampleH = 0;  // Default is 2 in ImFontConfig
                                    ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:86:37: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    int             fontOversampleV = 0;  // Default is 1 in ImFontConfig
                                    ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:123:1: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
ImVec2 EmToVec2(float x, float y);
^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:124:1: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
ImVec2 EmToVec2(ImVec2 v);
^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:124:17: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
ImVec2 EmToVec2(ImVec2 v);
                ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:132:1: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
ImVec2 PixelsToEm(ImVec2 pixels);
^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:132:19: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
ImVec2 PixelsToEm(ImVec2 pixels);
                  ^
In file included from tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h:11:
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui_assets.h:31:17: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    void * data = nullptr;
                ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui_assets.h:32:21: warning: default member initializer for non-static data member is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    size_t dataSize = 0;
                    ^
In file included from tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h:15:
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui_logger.h:17:10: warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    enum class LogLevel
         ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui_logger.h:27:17: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
    void LogGui(ImVec2 size=ImVec2(0.f, 0.f));
                ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui_logger.h:27:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec2'
    void LogGui(ImVec2 size=ImVec2(0.f, 0.f));
                            ^
In file included from tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h:17:
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:29:50: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
void ImageFromAsset(const char *assetPath, const ImVec2& size = ImVec2(0, 0),
                                                 ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:29:65: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec2'
void ImageFromAsset(const char *assetPath, const ImVec2& size = ImVec2(0, 0),
                                                                ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:30:27: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
                    const ImVec2& uv0 = ImVec2(0, 0), const ImVec2& uv1 = ImVec2(1,1),
                          ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:30:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec2'
                    const ImVec2& uv0 = ImVec2(0, 0), const ImVec2& uv1 = ImVec2(1,1),
                                        ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:30:61: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
                    const ImVec2& uv0 = ImVec2(0, 0), const ImVec2& uv1 = ImVec2(1,1),
                                                            ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:30:75: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec2'
                    const ImVec2& uv0 = ImVec2(0, 0), const ImVec2& uv1 = ImVec2(1,1),
                                                                          ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:31:27: error: unknown type name 'ImVec4'
                    const ImVec4& tint_col = ImVec4(1,1,1,1),
                          ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:31:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec4'
                    const ImVec4& tint_col = ImVec4(1,1,1,1),
                                             ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:32:27: error: unknown type name 'ImVec4'
                    const ImVec4& border_col = ImVec4(0,0,0,0));
                          ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:32:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec4'
                    const ImVec4& border_col = ImVec4(0,0,0,0));
                                               ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:36:56: error: unknown type name 'ImVec2'
bool ImageButtonFromAsset(const char *assetPath, const ImVec2& size = ImVec2(0, 0),
                                                       ^
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/image_from_asset.h:36:71: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ImVec2'
bool ImageButtonFromAsset(const char *assetPath, const ImVec2& size = ImVec2(0, 0),
                                                                      ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
8 warnings and 20 errors generated.

The structure of my files are:
> .vscode
> assets
> build
> external
    > build
    > hello_imgui
        >src
            >hello_imgui
             ... here are the .h files
CmakeLists.txt
hello_world.main.cpp

I cannot resolve the #include problems I'm facing and when I use brute force to resolve this error the ImVec2 error appears.
Edit: Error Log -
(base) alessandrodoro@MBP-Alessandro hello_imgui_template-1 % cmake --build build
[ 19%] Built target lunasvg
[ 21%] Built target stb_hello_imgui
[ 48%] Built target freetype
[ 53%] Built target imgui
[ 54%] Built target glad
[ 55%] Building CXX object external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/CMakeFiles/hello_imgui.dir/impl/dpi_aware.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/impl/dpi_aware.cpp:2:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/../hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:3:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h:25:
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/runner_params.h:250:5: error: unknown type name 'DpiAwareParams'
    DpiAwareParams dpiAwareParams;
    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/CMakeFiles/hello_imgui.dir/impl/dpi_aware.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/CMakeFiles/hello_imgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
(base) alessandrodoro@MBP-Alessandro hello_imgui_template-1 % 
 *  History restored 

(base) alessandrodoro@MBP-Alessandro hello_imgui_template-1 % cmake --build build 
[ 19%] Built target lunasvg
[ 21%] Built target stb_hello_imgui
[ 48%] Built target freetype
[ 53%] Built target imgui
[ 54%] Built target glad
[ 55%] Building CXX object external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/CMakeFiles/hello_imgui.dir/impl/dpi_aware.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/impl/dpi_aware.cpp:2:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/../hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h:3:
In file included from /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/hello_imgui.h:25:
/Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/runner_params.h:250:5: error: unknown type name 'DpiAwareParams'
    DpiAwareParams dpiAwareParams;
    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/CMakeFiles/hello_imgui.dir/impl/dpi_aware.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [external/hello_imgui/src/hello_imgui/CMakeFiles/hello_imgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2


Please [edit] your question to show us one single, full and complete copy-paste of the build log into the question. Don't leave anything out, and don't split it into multiple disconnected paragraphs. And as some errors seems to come from the header-file, please show it to us as well. And add comments on the lines in your code where you get the errors.

Pick one GUI framework and focus on getting it to work. Dropping wxWidgets simply because you couldn't immediately get it to work probably isn't the best move.

And please note that in C++ it's easy that one single error could cause multiple error messages. Which you should really just take one error message at a time and fix that. Starting from the first. Fixing that might fix quite a lot of errors following.

I would ignore third-party "project templates" for now. Make sure it works without those templates, without VSCode, perhaps even without CMake. Try to compile it directly in the terminal first.

You're not building using the CMake generated build files, you use the Visual Studio Code default code-runner plugin, which you have not configured to build with C++11 (or later) standard. And unfortunately Clang defaults to the very old C++98 standard. Please take some time to read the official documentation for Using Clang in Visual Studio Code.

Regarding the first comment by @HolyBlackCat, wxWidgets is a generic GUI framework for applications. ImGUI libraries are designed to be more used by games which have control of the whole display. They are not generic UI frameworks for normal applications.


I am trying to use only one GUI framework, but unless I fix the #include header files problem I have to bounce to this solution


The issue with wxWidgets, and its solution, is very likely the same as you have now: You don't build using the CMake generated build files. If you fix the configuration to build using the CMake generated build files, then wxWidgets will likely work as well.


I don't know how to make it work without these templates: as I said I am new to the argument and the most I can do is to start with some tutorial and then try to understand the matter.
I have read the official documentation and applied all I could to, but I am unable to understand what would be my next move


If a guide recommends you use some noname's "project template", ditch it and find a better guide. "what would be my next move" The first step is deciding what framework you want to focus on, wxWidgets or ImGui.

how do I compile using using the cmake generated build files?

I think my first step should really be worrying about how to import external libraries in C++ and make them work. If I am unable to do so, wxWidgets, Imgui or whatever GUI I choose won't work

First of all: stop changing all the includes to use absolute paths. You should learn how to configure your build system with the proper include paths. Secondly: stop using the VSCode runner system, as it is completely distinct from CMake and will only serve to confuse you. See that g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile invocation in your last paste? That invokes the C++ compiler with zero information about where to find any of it. Stick to CMake.

I would argue that the first step is to read the documentation I linked to earlier, and just get it to work with a simple "hello world" type program. Once you have that figured out, continue to learn the very basics of C++, using text-only programs, as when you start to mix in graphics (of any kind) you dive deep into a rabbit hole that is hard to get out of or to make sense of unless you have the basics done. When you get to this stage, it shouldn't be hard to figure out how to modify your configuration to build using arbitrary commands (like using CMake etc.).

Coming back to CMake: it looks like you got it to generate the build system successfully, now you need to actually build it. That is  done by invoking cmake --build build (and yes, you can convince VSCode to build via CMake too), and your executable will be generated somehwere in build, I'm guessing build/hello_world_.

And if you want to use CMake, then please learn the basics of that as well. Don't just copy-paste code or configuration you don't understand. That's called cargo cult programming, and it's not a good thing. Good books, good tutorials, good documentation will learn you how to not end up in tutorial hell, where you get something working but don't know how to modify it to fit your needs, or how to make things yourself.

And a last note: I don't know what you have been told, but programming and software development is hard. Like playing instruments, or being able to create beautiful paintings, it's a skill that needs to be learned from the ground up, and it takes time and a lot of effort. And you never stop learning new things, you must always continue to evolve and get better. But on the other hand, once you get past the initial hurdles, it's really fun and rewarding. I wouldn't want to do anything else.

Thank you @Someprogrammerdude, I appreciate the comments. I guess I gotta stop being lazy

Ignoring your failures with the VSCode file runner (seriously, don't use that), it looks like you missed the hint in your CMakeLists.txt. You can build your CMake project using
cmake --build build

and run it by running
build/hello_world_


When I run the command it starts then stops at [55%] with error: unknown type name DpiAwareParams. I'll edit the question to include the full log.
Also, I cannot seem to understand how to change from the VSCode file runner to cmake

dpi_aware.h does not contain an #include "hello_imgui.h" on line 3. Did you make any modifications to the files in external/hello_imgui?

I just cloned the hello_imgui_template repository on my mac, ran cmake -B build . and cmake --build build and it Just Worked(tm) so maybe try throwing everything away and resuming.

The only modification I made was to include the absolute path in the #include "hello_imgui.h". I know I shouldn't, but without it it keeps giving me the hello_imgui.h file not found

hello_imgui/dpi_aware.h includes imgui.h, not hello_imgui.h. Revert that change. If that still does not work, throw everything away and try building a fresh clone. That way you are sure there are no other accidental changes. I just proved that a clean checkout compiles properly.

just ran in succession cmake -B build and cmake --build build and now it builds successfully! but in my build folder there is no hello_world_ file which I can run with build/hello_world_

Ah, right. It created a build/hello_world_.app for me. Which is a native macOS bundle. You can do open build/hello_world_.app instead, or double-click the .app in Finder.

You also where right, just changed the absolute path from hello_imgui.h to imgui.h: the error has changed which I guess Is progress, now It gives me /Users/alessandrodoro/hello_imgui_template-1/external/hello_imgui/external/imgui/imgui.h:283:5: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'

That is impossible. The CMakeLists.txt clearly specifies C++17. What command produced this error?

I simply tried to run the hello_world.main.cpp in VSCode

And I have no clue how to help you with that. Good luck.

Thank you @Botje, I appreciated the help

Also: when I try to run it in VSCode it generates the error mentioned above, but when I run the hello_world_.app it runs smoothly. I have no idea what is happening or why

Because VSCode uses a fundamentally different build system by default, which you did not configure properly. I suppose there is a CMake plugin for VS Code but I have not tried it.
